# Web Crypto API decryption failing with RSA-OAEP

Tags: javascript, ssl, encryption, openssl, webcrypto-api

I have generated private key as following:

```bash
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048

openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -in private_key.pem -out private_key_pkcs8.pem -nocrypt
```

The  private key is embedded in the code snippet. Then I ecrypted a plaintext like the following:

```bash
echo -n "abcdef" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public_key.pem | openssl base64 > enc_simple.txt
```

This is also embedded in the code snippet. If I do the following:

```bash
base64 -d enc_simple.txt > enc_simple.bin
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private_key_pkcs8.pem -in enc_simple.bin -out decrypted_simple.txt
```

I get back "abcdef". SO with `openssl` everything is working. Then I want to recreate this entire scenario using [`Web Crypto API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) but the decryption is failing. Importing the private key is ok but the rest fails with `OperationError` with no error message. It is extremely obscure and hard to debug.

I have also ran:

```bash
od -An -vtu1 enc_simple.bin
```

to see the `Uint8Array` values and compare them with what I get from `str2ab` from the codesnippet. They match!

So I am stuck with no error message. I am trying to understand why the decryption is failing.

```js
const encryptedData = `gLiN3BLWTxbwpE5bwcFiB7Y/nK0H4iz9lK0sehMIJtoAPibDPZ8EYp8EnzsGFlKC
+GXse6Ka5YC7UKYn7xUvfBbCDSY7RJ/J9oAzpCEHvCnFOmrsvUtNEhP4w3LTaKL/
qKmjQZaPlZNWCmrzrW3g2A6DUCqLx5EQwCcwME2WjYVhuMZfZOKqtp+uukJMUf3h
cC9J8QkPCk1NZogCad29b7q7JLN1uWEQzOUgB6BqJfAp8kL92dftOy2gpWoGYraI
YPU3Tmp12txMyUY0yKsr4c2dOzxwWUW+ZssVkc6ZGqFVufADziZDp2sfFaz8yBuI
qek7S0KXd6A7qWBYBrzzyw==`; //abcdef
const privKeyPEM=`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`
const
    atob = (window || self)?.atob,
    subtle = (window || self).crypto.subtle,
    trimWs = (s) => s.replace(/\s*/g,""),
    trimHeader = (s) => s.replace(/-----(?:BEGIN|END) PRIVATE KEY-----/gi, "");
async function importPrivateKey (pemkey) {
    const binaryKey = atob(trimWs(trimHeader(pemkey)));
    const keyBuffer = new Uint8Array(binaryKey.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < binaryKey.length; i++) {
        keyBuffer[i] = binaryKey.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return await subtle.importKey(
        "pkcs8",
        keyBuffer,
        { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-256"},
        false,
        ["decrypt"]
    );
}
async function decryptData (privateKey, encryptedData) {
      const decrypted = await subtle.decrypt(
          { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-256"},
          privateKey,
         str2ab(atob(trimWs(encryptedData)))
      );
      return (new TextDecoder('utf-8')).decode(decrypted);
}
function str2ab (binaryStr) {
    const len = binaryStr.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryStr.charCodeAt(i); // Accurately map each char to a byte
    }
    return bytes; // Convert to ArrayBuffer
};


(async () => {
  try {
    const privKey = await importPrivateKey(privKeyPEM);
    console.log(privKey);
    const decrypted = await decryptData(privKey, encryptedData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Err:", err, "Err.massage:", err.message);
  }
})()
```

Comment: [openssl-rsautl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man1/openssl-rsautl.html) uses PKCS#1 v1.5 as default padding, while your WebCrypto code uses OAEP. For successful decryption, the same paddings are required.

Comment: So my command while generating `openssl pkcs8 ...` wasn't taken into consideration? Is the private key in the wrong format?

Comment: You want to use JWT with Web Cryptography API. Here's a complete working example of key generation and importing using only Web Cryptography API https://gist.github.com/deiu/2c3208c89fbc91d23226?permalink_comment_id=4821385#gistcomment-4821385

Comment: @guest271314 I am particularly interested in asymettric key decryption using RSA. Topaco might have a lead here, but I am trying to understand how to do what he means

Comment: Then use RSA for the algorithm name. That doesn't change anything re using "jwk". I just happened to be using Ed25519 in the example.

Comment: @guest271314 I understand JWT can be an option here. But for learning purposes I am trying to understand why this example is failing and how to fix it

Comment: @guest271314 I posted a whole example, run the code snippet and you can observe the result.

Comment: The padding has nothing to do with the key format. Take a look at the link posted in my first comment and look at the options `-pkcs, -oaep, -x931, -raw`. Since WebCrypto does not support PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (s. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt#parameters)), the only option is to use OAEP on the OpenSSL side.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see the bottom half of the code in the snippet. All I can say is use `"jwk"` and `TypedArray`s. That's what I got working after a lot of testing. Now I can successfully generate, encrypt, decrypt, export, and import using Web Cryptography API alone.

Comment: Note that OAEP has a number of parameters (e.g. OAEP and MGF1 digest) that must be chosen identically on both sides for compatibility.

Comment: @Topaco ok so what you are saying is this part needs:
```echo -n "abcdef" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public_key.pem | openssl base64 > enc_simple.txt``` to be changed to ```echo -n "abcdef" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -oaep -pubin -inkey public_key.pem | openssl base64 > enc_simple.txt``` ?? Is that it?

Comment: AFAIK, `openssl rsautl` uses SHA1 for OAEP, which cannot be changed. However, it is possible to apply OAEP with SHA256 with [`openssl -pkeyutl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man1/openssl-pkeyutl.html) (see in particular the section *RSA ALGORITHM*).

Comment: @Topaco Ok so I tried the -oeap above and it really generated a different encrypted text which I was not able to decode using openssl unless I also provided -oaep. But this also failed with the webcrypto api, so now I am thinking `SHA-256` should be replaced with `SHA-1` based on what you are saying. Or I can use the pkeyutils as you described to to keep using `SHA-256`. That means I need to change the way generate the private key then. I will try to look into it. But my tiny head is mush atm.

Comment: It is not necessary to use SHA-1. In the context of `openssl-pkeyutl`, the options `rsa_mgf1_md` and `rsa_oaep_md` can be used to set the MGF1 and the OAEP digest to SHA256. SHA-1 is not known to be a security issue in the context of OAEP (see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/112032)), but it should no longer be used for the sole reason of eliminating it from the ecosystem.

Comment: I think you shoud stick with Web Cryptography API the whole way and not use `openssl` at all.

Comment: *...That means I need to change the way generate the private key then...* Note that the padding has nothing to do with the key in the first place. On the OpenSSL side, the padding and the padding parameters are specified during encryption/decryption and not when the key is generated.

Comment: You may be assuming a relation between padding and key because padding and padding parameters are specified on the WebCrypto side when the key is generated. However, this is a peculiarity of the WebCrypto API, which wants to ensure in this way that a key is only used for one purpose. From a technical point of view, however, padding and key generation are independent of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenSSL *rsautl* encryption uses PKCS#1 v1.5 padding by default, while the WebCrypto code applies OAEP with SHA256 (which specifies SHA256 for *both* digests, the OAEP and the MGF1 digest). Therefore decryption fails.

Since WebCrypto does not support PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, OAEP with SHA256 must be used on the OpenSSL side for decryption to be successful.

OpenSSL *rsautl* supports OAEP, but only with SHA1. To use SHA256, OpenSSL *pkeyutl* must be applied. With the option `-pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep` OAEP is specified, with the options `-pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256` the OAEP and the MGF1 digest are set to SHA256, altogether:

```
echo -n "abcdef" | openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256 | openssl base64 > enc_simple.txt
```

A ciphertext generated in this way can be decrypted with the posted WebCrypto code (for this test I used the private key from your posted WebCrypto code and extracted the public key for the encryption from it):

```js
const encryptedData = `ETL+N6TbCcU+qoSrtVHqamrcLBM2upvS04+rvjeSL3ZA370jDMDLMjzszEakVJ7E
cA8mmY0GAK/ACFYV5Xc3KPXZVWFDaeTAu4tWY/TEftou/3zBWP9LjF4tViqWmxwC
3zgXM6lFaRBJMU/hIdc2mjNNS8/Rvc4HIS+6WBPXK50AOPySuak6m1EU3Zp2xeny
kGzH6+qotvJ3BC+OTXMAhaFwm+5hURY6rfAlYy5VX5NT2aD0FL0ggRF69Y+SMFZa
DDmaTiV1OwHuErm1T1k26QTgGcX/W+MWIlFBDXbJZxbIKIaHqquK2mN7qrGEQKVz
Ddh8MrfBs1aihAqgkXdLxg==`; //abcdef
const privKeyPEM=`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDJiQlvlYbTqi/W
bLa7nzaF4Wz+ypQa01HD+UMHX25Uv3n6P69ucKs/OOdWbcenknAmSBK/VzgIsjlm
vak3y1LoYImMhm8R26Arv8Fv7jwQkbBxVnOn6yfTL2h1SRK+zFzWumfbl2vp7POG
s7CRQaK0HFPKroVlYHlinTlYXSlFqdaknH2ip1J2YPJ3O4w0/ME8gBZ0Mj1XkokB
Qc0Lk76BpvfTuBbzvLYI4bq0/jSoM6ANecqK+T/7/aSFxh2x8acJ/xzJg2H7I+de
pXZ1M9Mz0x94jWRfc9Q9qLgY6AuX7MUyb2YEs+vMxcim60fvktHAaXvn9vM0eauC
B+hpThohAgMBAAECggEAINub0zqAwe/EXuRYopxhqlBHkf77SKhdc2MnX4NanKyf
OYK6mnn6IZOoe/noDFUevc8QZ2vT8e8E1tBjT3px6PscUfH1F+dD5P4djp874cOv
Dbt3ndAELTVUhZLFYKA3HrdDiZTVfk0oozSWvAgEe/MGYkwz6YRiJgbWO6bsvLOa
5Ehhd7Ocxbs4B389ad3bVzRkk02/IRDEeO1z0+22Wv1NIe0Spzl6FVLspL6JdmEu
60rpShfwN7D0G4TQYYp/9Sh+zt0ThIF4kqQoURx5E2uQaDUAT206itMG2mUWYSR1
M37U+46kpWBz0jDaRFmqlySKrmkbx7kWXju8wP1ZAQKBgQDvlq4B3jAPd+Pu/Rxw
GORV5S8PdJrkQnx8BeAviGAVc2w6EMyRWusVzL95mpRS0t0E5xZtB2kLkVU/I08b
j+WqrGFqFp8niXYnJsien8nfLct0AhJVvVaPtt8lHP9SKniBOZc0owzFljnt+4/6
M4ifAiKvJYOqPSdGpJgvJq4TsQKBgQDXVxJCjUNInb4p0WWljxdcMpgSDPn53+BG
M/MrxVbTOvHhKsbNlglYxT/87J+8lFKS5Y9EkpqekCY1aGJ0PYfLBMowvNAwiP2s
89++PTuEO/hK16Xb8znZ7rUGdJdRUitBN8iVkWNLA2pzalcZkkHbIWQbDuJOPbdO
bo1u06U5cQKBgAgeliUQD5bmnD3kLAuMfGiAzNh8PieQLUHSvSc/OupfMALDwPsI
FsF1X+PSHka0SLM61aK6RpASy83I94xakxD2qJJ808X2PZ/UC6Z8ic3bcnKrA04O
jZlvPB643do+ADl45yvsfqlPjwUGqnlzN6UT4HMJFW42hlc5isLGT83xAoGBANT/
UxhxEfRp0wcaECjKeJjBkpmILFp0jynhiM3qzA7zZv0JissfdO9RbBGJHBczvtl+
J0/0kuv0OVbqgTfpBMBTZIsAuAzJ8+F2+AD8IDqT9uxQkcYVt0tRSc2w1VuioxZH
TyhiPoycPFcdADpS6MEPLi11c3NgqEf0IgFVZ0CBAoGBAMybGC+IImSDpZzLaSpz
KAD6Vyto7eK4pENH8bPcM2Hpy7aMGJkr6Q/NT34p/vSfFG2gm8ueILhvqQ8yB6h6
gtfHOEu7CC/8WL4Y/WehrpD+fTTSOd/C+JZJbXjHjJ55NX1JzgeCPWJP2QOyXE85
VLq+2V8bhsQxi4JylnH6suLB
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`
const
    atob = (window || self)?.atob,
    subtle = (window || self).crypto.subtle,
    trimWs = (s) => s.replace(/\s*/g,""),
    trimHeader = (s) => s.replace(/-----(?:BEGIN|END) PRIVATE KEY-----/gi, "");
async function importPrivateKey (pemkey) {
    const binaryKey = atob(trimWs(trimHeader(pemkey)));
    const keyBuffer = new Uint8Array(binaryKey.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < binaryKey.length; i++) {
        keyBuffer[i] = binaryKey.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return await subtle.importKey(
        "pkcs8",
        keyBuffer,
        { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-256"},
        false,
        ["decrypt"]
    );
}
async function decryptData (privateKey, encryptedData) {
      const decrypted = await subtle.decrypt(
          { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-256"},
          privateKey,
         str2ab(atob(trimWs(encryptedData)))
      );
      return (new TextDecoder('utf-8')).decode(decrypted);
}
function str2ab (binaryStr) {
    const len = binaryStr.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryStr.charCodeAt(i); // Accurately map each char to a byte
    }
    return bytes; // Convert to ArrayBuffer
};


(async () => {
  try {
    const privKey = await importPrivateKey(privKeyPEM);
    //console.log(privKey);
    const decrypted = await decryptData(privKey, encryptedData);
    console.log(decrypted)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Err:", err, "Err.massage:", err.message);
  }
})()
```

On the OpenSSL side it can be successfully decrypted with:

```
base64 -d enc_simple.txt > enc_simple.bin
openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey private_key_pkcs8.pem -in enc_simple.bin -out decrypted_simple.txt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256
```

Comment: I would not be able to figure it out myself. It looks like it is working. I will try to replicate it on  my side. But may Odin reserve a place for you in valhalla, thank you.